# Recharge time for heroes

Tags: clash-of-clans

If an attack is about to end (for any reason except going to loose) and your hero has sustained a small amount of damage, is it worth it to use their special ability to heal them? I am not sure exactly how the time a hero takes to recover from a battle is calculated, but it seems the more damage they take, the longer they have to recharge after the match. So I'm wondering, if right before the match ends, is it worth it to use their ability to bring up their health, or is there some part of the way the time is calculated so it takes longer if you had used the ability?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is worth it. Factors like how much damage they've been dealt the entire battle, or if their ability is up or down, have no bearing on how long a hero sleeps for. Only the amount of damage they currently have at the end of a battle will dictate how long a hero sleeps for.

If your hero heals back up to full either through the healing spell, healers, or using their ability, then they can be used immediately for another attack. So, even healing part of the way to full will reduce the amount of time a hero sleeps before being able to be utilized again.

Answer (score 1):

[Clash of Clans Wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Barbarian_King) claims that your Barbarian King (or Queen, or Warden) will sleep proportionally to the health they have at the end of the battle. It's simple math :

`Time Sleeping = Total Rest Time x %Hero Health Missing`

So in conclusion, yes it is definitely worth it using all your hero's abilities before the attack ends and I would even recomment NOT ending any attack with unused hero's ability.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `%damage` instead of `%health` as the more health, the less the time sleeping should be?